# Refreshing Code modifications - JHipster

Tags: refresh, jhipster

I'm a new user of this tool. After having installed the environment on my cpu, I tried first to add some code to the home component (for example).
Unfortunately, when I save my modifications and refresh the page, there is no update.
Do you may have some things to check if it happens ?

Comment: Did you run `yarn start`? It's required to recompile the TS https://jhipster.github.io/development/#working-with-angular

Comment: After correcting some node dependencies and re-run `yarn start` , it finally works, Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the comments - just run `yarn start`, as explained in the documentation, to have TypeScript compilation and hot reload working.